# Creating an order form - Trouble turning order button for each product into one button

Tags: php, html, forms, input, html-lists

I am busy creating an order system.

I am having issues trying to create a form that requires only one order button.

Currently the form is for each product result. The user has the ability to enter in a quantity desired of a certain product, then can order the product based on the quantity chosen. The item id and quantity chosen are then added to sessions.

The problem with this, is that if there are 5 items, there are 5 order buttons.

I am trying to simplify this, where for 5 products, there will be only one order button controlling the entire selection of products.

Here is the code relating to this:

```
//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 

$dataQuery = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE upper(`desc`) LIKE '%" 
   . implode("%' AND upper(`desc`) LIKE '%", $keywords_array) 
   . "%' ORDER BY `desc`";

$data = mysql_query($dataQuery) or die(mysql_error());

$tempVar = 0;
//And we display the results 
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
$prId = $result['id'];
$prRefCode = $result['refCode'];
$prDesc = $result['desc'];
$prPack = $result['pack'];
$prMeasure = $result['measure'];
$prQuantity = $result['quantity'];
$prDeptCode = $result['deptCode'];
$prTaxable = $result['taxable'];
$prPrice1 = $result['price1'];
$prPrice2 = $result['price2'];
$prCrdCode = $result['crdCode'];
$prCost1 = $result['cost1'];
$prCost2 = $result['cost2'];

if ($tempVar == 0) {
$pageContent .= '
<p><u>All prices are inclusive of VAT</u></p>
<table class="searchResults" border="1" align="center" width="90%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Stock Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Packsize</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>In-Stock?</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Submit</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
';
}

    $pageContent .= '
<tr>
    <td>' . $prId . '</td>
    <td>' . $prDesc . '</td>
    <td>' . $prPack . 'x' . $prSize . ' ' . $prMeasure . '</td>
    <td>R' . $prPrice1 . '</td>
';
    if (empty($prQuantity)) {
        $pageContent .= '
<td>No</td>
';
    } else {
        $pageContent .= '
<td>Yes</td>
';
    }
    $pageContent .= '
    <form id="validated" action="" method="post">
    <td>            
            <div>
                <input type="text" 
onkeydown="return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey 
                || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false) 
                || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
                || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9) 
                || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40) 
                || (event.keyCode==46) )" 
                name="quantity" size ="2" 
                value ="1" 
                style="background: #F4F4F4;
                       font-family: Monaco, monospace;" />
            </div>            
    </td>
    <td>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $prId . '" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Order" />
            </div>            
    </td>
    </form>     
</tr>
';
$tempVar ++;
}



//This counts the number of results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
$anymatches = mysql_num_rows($data);
if ($anymatches == 0) {
    $pageContent .= '
<p>Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query</p>
<!-- end .aliLeft --></div>
';
}

if ($anymatches > 0 and count($tempVar) == count($anymatches)) {
    $pageContent .= '
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- end .aliLeft --></div>
';
}
```

As you can see, when the user searches for a product, the mysql table is queried, if results are found, then they are returned.

In this process, the form is created for each result.

What I am trying to do, is extend this form to cover the entire set of results, then have only one input for "Order", so essentially, the user can enter quantities on various products, then have those products and quantities added to their order.

Does anyone have any advice on how i would go about this task?

I would appreciate any input what so ever, thank you!

EDITED BY OP:

And here is the code controlling the instance of a user clicking on the order button:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['order']))
{
$_SESSION['order'] = array();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['quantity']))
{
$_SESSION['quantity'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Order' and $_POST['quantity'] > 0)
{
// Add item to the end of the $_SESSION['order'] array
$_SESSION['order'][$_POST['id']] = $_POST['id'];
$_SESSION['quantity'][$_POST['id']] = $_POST['quantity'];
header('Location: .');
exit();
}
```

And here is the code that configures the quantity value for totalling the order:

```
$total = 0;
if (count($order) > 0)
{
foreach ($order as $product)
{
    mysql_data_seek( $totalsSql, 0);  //<- this line, to reset the pointer for every EACH.
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($totalsSql))
    {
     $prodId = $row['id'];
     $prodPrice1 = $row['price1'];
     $prodQuantity = $quantity[$prodId];
    if ($product == $prodId) 
        {
        $total += ($prodPrice1*$prodQuantity);
        break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

EDITED BY OP:

See revised controller code:

```
$productQuantities=$_POST['quantity'];
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Order' and $productQuantities > 0)
{
foreach($productQuantities as $productId=>$quantityS)
{
    if ($quantityS > 0) 
        {
        $_SESSION['order']["$productId"] = $productId;
        $_SESSION['quantity']["$productId"] = $quantityS;
        header('Location: .');
        exit();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make following change to your code:

```
..................
...................

<form id="validated" action="" method="post">
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{

..........................
.................
......................

    <td>            
            <div>
                <input type="text" 
onkeydown="return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey 
                || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false) 
                || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
                || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9) 
                || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40) 
                || (event.keyCode==46) )" 




                // Notice that I have changed name="quantity" to name="quantity[$prId]"
                //    VVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
                name="quantity[$prId]" size ="2" 
                //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^



                value ="1" 
                style="background: #F4F4F4;
                       font-family: Monaco, monospace;" />
            </div>            
    </td>

...............
.................
................
...............

</tbody>
</table>
<!-- end .aliLeft --></div>
</form>';
}
```

Now Get the quantities for product ids in the php file where the form submits:-

```
<?php
$productQuantities=$_POST['quantity'];


if (!isset($_SESSION['order']))
{
    $_SESSION['order'] = array();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['quantity']))
{
    $_SESSION['quantity'] = array();
}    

foreach($productQuantites as $productId=>$quantity)
{    
    if ($quantity>0)
    {
        // Add item to the end of the $_SESSION['order'] array
        $_SESSION['order'][$productId] = $productId;
        $_SESSION['quantity'][$productId] = $quantity;
        header('Location: .');
        exit();
    } 

}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. Could you do me a very big favour and include the code that was edited into  my op as your example for getting the quantities for for product id's. I am quite new to php and although i do grasp what you're saying, im having trouble putting 2 and 2 together as far as that is concerned. Thanks!

Comment: yes sure, but I could not understand which bit is confusing you? As I have already included all the code.

Comment: What goes inside of the foreach?

Comment: I have edited the second part check it out -- And your totalling code I guess will remain same. But I am not sure

Comment: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /path/index.php on line 31` This is the foreach. Should the first line not read `$productQuantities=$_POST['quantity'];`?

Comment: `foreach($productQuantites as $productId=>$quantity)` was not spelt correctly, but after changing this, it still procudes the same warning, also, a var dump on the array produces [(prodid)] => [(prodId)] ,for some reason it is not adding the user supplied quantity, although it is entering its row id

Comment: Okay i got it working with the addition of the code that has been edited into my op. The problem now is that if a user enters quantities on more than one line, and then clicks on order, only the first line that has a quantity entered is added to the order. Any idea why this is?

Comment: I solved it, the problem came because the script was being exited before the loop could be completed. Was so simple too! I really appreciate all of your help, thank you!